# Java 8 lambda for each call method and addAll

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

I would like to replace the following code to utilize Java 8 streams if possible:

```
final List<Long> myIds = new ArrayList<>();
List<Obj> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
// myObject populated...

for (final Obj ob : myObjects) {
   myIds.addAll(daoClass.findItemsById(ob.getId()));
}
```

`daoClass.findItemsById` returns `List<Long>`

Can anybody advise the best way to do this via lambdas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
List<Long> myIds = myObjects.stream()
    .map(Obj::getId)
    .map(daoClass::findItemsById)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flatMap which combines multiple list into a single list.

```
myObjects.stream()
    .flatMap(ob -> daoClass.findItemsById(ob.getId()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

flatMap it!

```
source.stream()
      .flatMap(e -> daoClass.findItemsById(e.getId).stream())     
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```